# Laravel 5 Application For More Than 1 Site

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm not sure how to phrase my title so I had done the best I could.

I am putting together a Laravel 5 application to which multiple sites can pay to use for their company. This is an application that stores site related content in my database. So all data will be attached to a specific company (site).

Lets say there are 3 sites that want to use my application.

- www.site1.com
- www.site2.com
- www.site3.com

When a user goes to either of those sites and wants to access lets say the name of my project lets say:

- www.site1.com/projectname
- www.site2.com/projectname
- www.site3.com/projectname

It would then be sent to my site where they would log into my system and it would be able to grab the url and match it verify that it is a company that uses my system and then it would be able to keep separate the users and data separated from the other companies who use it.

Is this something that could be worked and if so any thoughts or ideas upon this.

I watched a series on this type of thing from net.tutsplus.com https://code.tutsplus.com/courses/building-multitenant-apps-in-laravel and have the basic idea however the video doesn't cover the situation like mine would with the other sites url coming into play.

Comment: You are on the right track, you are building a multitenant app. There's no problem how many sites you'll have, Laravel will respond to all of them, as long as you have configured your server. You'll need to add all of your sites to your server, point DNS and so.

Comment: I'm saying though all 3 of those sites are NOT mine. Those are all client sites.

Comment: Maybe you should fetch the referral link to know which company the client has come from, then save it in a session. When they create an account in your application, store their referral link alongside their details. For accurate results, verify that the referral links come from the sites you know, then block the rest!